# Is there a wii that is not homebrewable?

Tags: mods, nintendo-wii, homebrew

I want homebrew & bootmii on a Wii, but I don't currently own a Wii.

Is there any particular Wii that that this won't work for?

Comment: I think that you are asking if you can just buy any Wii and then be able to do homebrew & bootmii on it.  But you don't actually say so.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @Brythan yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

## There are currently seven exploits to install Homebrew on the latest version of the Wii's OS

According to Nintendo's Wii update history:

[https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2522/~/system-menu-update-history](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2522/%7E/system-menu-update-history)

The last update to the Wii was in 2010 to version 4.3.

The Homebrew wiki's installation page reads:

> The methods described in this tutorial covers the Smash Stack, Yu-Gi-OWNED!, Bathaxx, Return of the Jodi, Indiana Pwns, Eri HaKawai and Letterbomb exploits as these are the only methods working for 4.3

https://wiibrew.org/wiki/Homebrew_setup

And according to that wiki page's history, the lastest exploit to be created was `Return of the Jodi` in 2011, one year after Nintendo's final update. (This does not mean the exploits weren't updated since then.)

There can be unhomebrewable Wiis, if Nintendo out of the blue releases an update for the Wii, however I find that extremely unlikely. Even then, more exploits will be found for the new version.

Protip: Before you do anything, read the instalation instructions all the way through once.

Comment: If there is something wrong with my answer, could you please tell me?

Comment: You have no version numbers or anything which is what would be necessary to determine if something can be home brewed.  At best this should be a comment in my opinion.

Comment: To add you say yes with out much of a source. I would think this day and age Nintendo wouldn't be releasing many updates for the wii.

Comment: @William Ok, I've found new sources, including Nintendo's change log and the Homebrew wiki naming all 7 exploits that can be used for the same version of the Wii's OS. Is there any other information I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any particular Wii that that this won't work for?

Yes, there is one, although it's uncommon.

The Wii Mini does not have an SD card reader, and lacks any form of network access. (The wireless hardware been omitted, and there is no software support for the USB LAN Adapter or Wi-Fi USB Connector.) This leaves no way to load custom software onto the device.

The Wii Mini is physically much smaller than the standard Wii and has an unusual black-and-red color scheme, so it's easy to recognize and avoid.

Comment: Didn't even know these exist

Comment: The Wii Mini was released, with very little fanfare, around the same time as the Wii U. It had no new features (besides a lower price) and wasn't even available worldwide, so it was pretty easy to miss.

Comment: Based on my quick googling, on top of not having easily accessible ports, the Wii mini was not popular enough for someone to write a Home brew variant for it. It seems to have one USB connection, except it's soldered for internal use.

Comment: Just wanted to say that there now is a way to install homebrew on the Wii Mini, using a vulnerability in the bluetooth stack of the Wii. It's called "bluebomb". You can even bring back internet connection support (LAN only) using homebrew. So now, every Wii is homebrewable.